# speed up unoconv conversion process

Tags: unix, unoconv

I am converting xlsx file to csv using unoconv in unix. I find it very slow if file is above 20mb. It takes more than 10mins to convert. Is there a way to speed it up.

command I use is this.

```
unoconv -f csv testfile.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

Dag Wieers, the unoconv developer does answer this question saying that using latest LibreOffice is usually a good idea. Please have a look at this thread

https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/187